# How to extend the functionality of an ActiveRecord object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop, associations

I have a class called `Story` that is associated with a class called `User`.
I also have a class called `Parser` that extends Story with parsing abilities (such as finding the nouns, for example).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stories
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :title, :content
end

class Parser < Story
    def find_nouns
        self.content.do_something
    end
end
```

Say I want to create a new story for the first user in my database. Normally, I would simply do that using

```
User.first.stories.new(:title => 'Foo', :content => 'Bar')
```

How would I achieve that and still associate the record with the first story elegantly?

Something along these line:

```
User.first.stories.new(:title => 'Foo', :content => 'Bar').find_nouns
```

The problem is, the base class doesn't have access to the `find_nouns` method -- it belongs to StoryParser.

Comment: You can make `Parser` a module and just include it in `Story` class instead of inheriting. Or add `Parser` as a member of `Story` and delegate `find_nouns` calls to it.

Comment: what do you mean by `member of Story`?

Comment: Like this:
`class Story`
`attr_accessor :parser`
`def initialize`
`@parser = Parser.new(content)`
`end`
`delegate :find_nouns, :to => :parser`
`end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Parser` class looks like it should be a module mixed into either the `Story` class or instances, because it's one aspect of a story.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Here's the module:

```
module Parser
  def find_nouns
    ...
  end
end
```

Mix it into the class with `include`:

```
class Story
  include Parser
end
```

Or mix it into instances of `Story`:

```
@user.stories.first.extend(Parser).find_nouns
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not look like **Parser** is related to **Story**, parser should be it's own class and should have methods that receive a **Story** or just pure strings and parse them to do their work.

Stories do not "extract" nouns from themselves, so it does not really make sense to Parser be a subclass of Story.

```
story = Story.new(:content => 'some content')
parser = Parser.new
parser.find_nouns( story.content ) # would generate ['content']
```

Comment: I should have mentioned this is not my actual problem, it's just an example simple enough to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve. On a technical level, I am asking what kind of code is necessary to achieve what I am requesting. Thank you for you answer thus far :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean then, if you want to call the method to **Story**, why don't you just place it there?